# Ruby time in Days/hours/minutes between now and the second Tuesday of the month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 2.0.0 an rails 4.0.0.

I have a web service call that is going to run on the 1st of every month.

It's job is to schedule emails to go out on the second Tuesday of the month.

The "Scheduler" web service call has a parameter like this:

`?schedule_for_1d&1h&1m`

That would schedule the emails to go out 1 day, 1 hour, and 1 minute after the api call is executed.

Right before I make that API call I need to calculate the time, in days, hours, and minutes, between "`Time.now`" and the second Tuesday of the month, whenever that is.

How can I write that code out and get it in the format of the above "`1d&1h&1m`"?

Comment: I do not understand the parameter value. Is `1d&1h` equivalent to `25h`? If it is 10pm on Sunday night, and the emails are to go out that Tuesday at 3am, is it `1d&5h` or `2d&3h`?

Comment: `1d&1h` is equivalent to `25h`.

Comment: I am building [Tick](http://tickapp.herokuapp.com/) just to avoid developer have problems with schedulers anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
def scheduleSecondTuesday
  now = Time.now
  secondTuesday = 8 + (2-Time.local(now.year,now.month,1).wday) % 7
  s = Time.local(now.year,now.month,secondTuesday) - now
  dhm = [24*3600,3600,60].inject([]) { |a,b| x,s = s.divmod(b); a<<x }
  '?schedule_for_%dd&%dh&%dm' % dhm
end

scheduleSecondTuesday
# => "?schedule_for_5d&9h&48m"
```

One safety feature included here is that if the task that runs on the 1st of every month fails for some reason and runs some time prior to the second Tuesday or the month, it will still output the correct string.